# Como cambiar el nombre de un objeto en java

Tags: java, array, poo, arraylist, objeto

Estoy creando objetos de forma dinamica en java, pero tengo la duda si el nombre se cambia por automatico o no, estoy implementando lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de matrices: ");
    noMatrices = sc.nextInt();
    
    for (int i = 0; i<noMatrices; i++){
        System.out.println("Ingrese las filas: ");
        fila = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingrese las columnas: ");
        columna = sc.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre: ");
        nombre = sc.next();
        
        a = new Matriz(fila, columna, nombre);
        
        matrices.add(a);
        indice++;
    }
    
    for(int j = 0; j < matrices.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(matrices.get(j));
     }
```

**matrices** corresponde al arraylist creado anteriormente, pero al momento de que muestre, solo dice en consola **prueba.Matriz@567d299b**

> Cita en bloque

Comment: ¿Qué quisieras ver? Prueba con `matrices.get(j).getClass().getName()`.

Comment: El nombre que se le da al objeto "a", pero no sé si a como lo estoy haciendo, solo pone un nombre dentro, más no modifica el del objeto.

Comment: Si lo que quieres obtener es la propiedad `nombre` de los objetos (tercer parámetro pasado en el constructor), lo propio sería crear un *getter*  en la clase `Matriz` y usar dicho método para obtener el nombre: **`matrices.get(j).getNombre()`** (asumiendo que el *getter* se llama `getNombre()`).

Comment: Acuérdate de limpiar el bufer del teclado después de introducir un valor numérico, de los contrario no te cogería el String. Después de un nexInt "sc.nextLine();" para recibir luego el string del nombre, mejor "sc.nexLine();". Otra recomendación sería cerrar el teclado, pues dejarlo abierto te consumiría recursos "sc.close();" Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres obtener es la propiedad `nombre` de los objetos (tercer parámetro pasado en el constructor), lo propio sería crear un *getter*  en la clase `Matriz` y usar dicho método para obtener el nombre: **`matrices.get(j).getNombre()`** (asumiendo que el *getter* se llama `getNombre()`).

Por ejemplo:

```
public class Matriz {

    private int fila;
    private int columna;
    private String nombre;
    
    public Matriz (int fila, int columna, String nombre){
        this.fila=fila;
        this.columna=columna;
        this.nombre=nombre;
    }
    
    public String getNombre(){
        return this.nombre;
    }
    
    /*
        Puede que tu clase tenga más setter ... getter
    */
}
```

Dentro de `matrices` habrá objtetos del tipo `Matriz` y por tanto podrás usar cualquiera de sus métodos y/o propiedades disponibles en ese contexto:

```
for(int j = 0; j < matrices.size(); j++) {
        System.out.println(matrices.get(j).getNombre());
}
```